# Filtering data from a mysql table using a date range where date format is VACHAR ('AUG-18')

Tags: mysql-5.7

Sample Data

```
TRAINING_DATE    GENDER
AUG-18             M
AUG-18             F
SEPT-18            F
OCT-18             M
OCT-18             M
NOV-18             M
NOV-18             F
```

Expected Output.
Number of people trained between SEPT-18 and NOV-18

```
   F      M
   2      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your data differently. Storing year and month separately might be a good idea. You can do that like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN training_year int, ADD COLUMN training_month tinyint;

UPDATE your_table SET 
training_year = YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(TRAINING_DATE, '%b-%y')),
training_month = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(TRAINING_DATE, '%b-%y'));
```

When you don't need your `TRAINING_DATE` column anymore, you can drop it.

Now you could query your table like this:

```
SELECT gender,
       COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE training_year = 2018
  AND training_month BETWEEN 9 AND 11
GROUP BY gender;
```

- read more about the `STR_TO_DATE()` function and some more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)